# Waterline UUID type and validation

Tags: validation, model, sails.js, uuid, waterline

I would like to create a "Customer" models which has a uuid field as a primary key. It seems to be simple but it is not as Waterline doesn't include any native validator for this.

How to edit this code so that I can have an uuid as a unique primary key for this model ?

```
module.exports = {
  identity: 'customer',
  connection: 'mysql',
  attributes: {
    // Properties
    uuid: {
      type: 'string',
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
      uuidv4: true,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    // …
  }
};
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I was finding ways to do exact the same thing and found out two means.

1. **By using packages like `node-uuid`**

   ```
   var uuid = require('node-uuid');
   ```

   , then in model

   ```
   autoPK: false,

   attributes: {
       uuid: {
           type: 'string',
           primaryKey: true,
           defaultsTo: function (){ return uuid.v4(); },
           unique: true,
           index: true,
           uuidv4: true
       },
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Set autoPK to false is to prevent waterline from automatically generating ids.

   Reference: [Feature Request: GUIDs as Primary Keys](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/94)
2. **By using packages like `node-uuid` and `beforeCreate`**

   ```
   var uuid = require('node-uuid');
   ```

   , then in model

   ```
   autoPK: false,

   attributes: {
       uuid: {
           type: 'string',
           primaryKey: true,
           unique: true,
           index: true,
           uuidv4: true
       },
       // ...
   },

   beforeValidate: function(values, next) {
       values.uuid = uuid.v4();
       next();
   }
   ```

   Reference:

   - [How can I write sails function on to use in Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386573/how-can-i-write-sails-function-on-to-use-in-controller)
   - [Callbacks on create](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#callbacks-on-create)

I prefer the first one cause it's simpler, but it depends.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried both solutions based on node-uuid. I have a function which populates my database with 100 test records. Only the first is inserted because next generated uuids collide. I don't aunderstand why.

Comment: @mastergap probably because you were generating a uuid in your model as the default value instead of making it a function that is executed by waterline to generate the default value.

Comment: Is "uuidv4" somewhere nonobvious in the docs? I can't find it.

Comment: Also, you say "beforeCreate" but then do "beforeValidate". Is one better suited, here?

Comment: Please update this as node-uuid is deprecated

https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid